# Who's in on the master plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-twelve

What characters exactly are in on the grand rouse in *Ocean's Twelve* (i.e. that they've already agreed with Lamark to steal the egg and humiliate the night fox in return for $160+ million before the plot even starts) from the beginning?

I realize that Rusty is, but is Danny (especially since Rusty mutters to Reuben not to tell Danny as he's leaving the initial planning room)? Is Lahiri (Rusty's old girlfriend) in on it — and thus is her whole investigation of them legitimate, or just part of the show? Do certain characters find out along the way (like Tess)?

Comment: I didn't see the movie for a while but I think Isabel Lahiri was genuinely tracking Danny and the Ocean's Twelve. My understanding is that it is Danny's part of the deal: make her acquointed to their world so that she will agree to reunite with Lamark, and continue her relation with Danny. That's similar to the first movie: one has to choose between the money and the girl, but they outsmart everybody and get both.